# pointer output code. I'm getting opposite of the answer. Please explain how is it happening

Tags: c++, pointers, output

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

//swap function
void swap (char *x, char *y) 
{
  char *t = x;
  x = y;
  y = t;
}

int main()
{
   char *x = "geeksquiz";
   char *y = "geeksforgeeks";
   char *t;
   swap(x, y);
   cout<<x << " "<<y;
   t = x;
   x = y;
   y = t; 
   cout<<" "<<x<< " "<<y;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: After dry run, I am getting the output as "geeksforgeeks geeksquiz geeksquiz geeksforgeek" whereas the output is "geeksquiz geeksforgeeks geeksforgeeks geeksquiz"

Comment: Your swap() function is not actually swapping anything, since it takes its input parameters by value, thus copies of the inputs are made, and you are swapping the copies around, not the originals

Comment: Remember that function arguments in C++ are passed *by value*, which means the values in the call are copied into the functions local argument variables. Assigning to a local variable only affect the local variable itself and not the original value. You need to pass the arguments *by reference*.

Comment: Geeksforgeeks is a garbage collection. If you want to learn C++, prefer a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Also see: [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Also, all literal strings in C++ are really *constant* arrays of characters (including the null-terminator). So all pointers to such string literals needs to be constant as well: `const char* x = "geeksquiz";`.

Comment: Both of my comments (about passing by reference and about literal strings being constant) should be taught in any decent book or class. So instead of using bad online tutorials (like geek for geeks, or so-called "competition" sites) invest in [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) and take proper classes, to learn C++ and programming and computer science properly.

Comment: Thannk you so much. Got that :)

Answer (score 1):

In the swap function that you have implemented, you are modifying local x and y, which has no effect on the x and y in the main function. There are two solutions for that.

1- Adding another level of pointer to the parameters:

```
void swap_pointer (char **x, char **y) 
{
  char *t = *x;
  *x = *y;
  *y = t;
}
```

and then calling the function as `swap_pointer(&x, &y);`

2- changing the function parameters to reference types:

```
void swap_reference (char *&x, char *&y) 
{
  char *t = x;
  x = y;
  y = t;
}
```

and then calling the function as `swap_reference(x, y);`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main problems with your code both of which are explained below:

##### Problem 1

In C++, we cannot have `char*` pointing to a **string literal**. This means, the following statements in your program are **invalid**:

```
char *x = "geeksquiz";      //INVALID
char *y = "geeksforgeeks";  //INVALID
```

##### Solution to Problem 1

To solve this, we have to add a **low-level const** to the pointers as shown below:

```
//--vvvvv---------------------------------->const added here
    const char *x = "geeksquiz";
//--vvvvv---------------------------------->const added here
    const char *y = "geeksforgeeks";
```

##### Problem 2

In addition to the above problem, the function named `swap` in your program takes argument **by value**. This means, whatever changes you make to those arguments inside the function will not be reflected back on the original passed arguments.  This in turn means that you're actually performing a swap on the copies and not on the original arguments which explains why you don't get your expected result.

##### Solution to Problem 2

You can solve this by passing the argument **by reference** which can be done by making the parameter to be *reference to `const char*`* as shown below:

```
#include<iostream>

//---------vvvvv---------vvvvv----------->const added here
void swap (const char *&x,const char *&y) 
//---------------------^--------------^--> & added here
{
//vvvvv---------------------------------->const added here 
  const char *t = x;
  x = y;
  y = t;
}

int main()
{
//-vvvvv------------------------------->const added here
   const char *x = "geeksquiz";
//-vvvvv------------------------------->const added here
   const char *y = "geeksforgeeks";
   swap(x, y);  //pass arguments by reference
   std::cout<<x << " "<<y;
   return 0;
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/fJJsLh8Ve)

##### Alternative solution

Note that you can also use `std::string` instead of using pointers as shown below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
void swap (std::string &x,std::string &y) 
{
  std::string temp = x;
  x = y;
  y = temp;
}

int main()
{
   std::string x = "geeksquiz";

   std::string y = "geeksforgeeks";
   swap(x, y);  //pass arguments by reference
   std::cout<<x << " "<<y;
  
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/nHbvE6Cu6)